# MS Access 2010 Forms!FormName!ControlName returning nothing?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have the query

```
SELECT [Forms]![frmDataEntry]![Combo3];
```

I also have a form called frmDataEntry with a combo box called combo3 on it. The combo box has multiple values, and one is selected when I run the query. I used the macro expression builder to open the query when a button is pressed.

Similar/the same sql was working last night, from the same combo box. I have tried doing the some thing with different forms and controls, yet nothing returns a result. I also tried making a new query and putting in the sql again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `cboUserID` on `Form2` has the 47 selected for its bound value.

This query returns an empty field:

```
SELECT Forms!Form2!cboUserID;
```

Explicitly telling the db engine I want the combo's `.Value` property gives me a single slash character (`/`) as this query's result:

```
SELECT Forms!Form2!cboUserID.Value
```

Yet this query tells me "Long" as the data type of the combo's bound value, which is correct:

```
SELECT TypeName(Forms!Form2!cboUserID.Value)
```

So I tried the `CLng()` function to inform the db engine I want the combo's value as a Long Integer, and this query gave me 47 ... which is the selected value in the combo:

```
SELECT CLng(Forms!Form2!cboUserID.Value);
```

I have no idea why this is so; I've never tried this before.  I'll just suggest you try the appropriate data type conversion function for your combo.  [`CLng`; `CInt`; `CDbl`; `CStr`; `CDate`; etc]  Also I used Access 2007 for my tests because I don't have 2010.  I hope 2010 behaves similarly for you.

Comment: Putting in .value worked, thanks! I originally put .value in, but it was inside the square brackets which resulted in a syntax error, so I assumed that couldn't be done, lesson learned. I will keep in mind the conversion functions though, may need them one day.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I don't understand why just adding `.Value` worked for you but not for me.  Anyway I'm glad it worked for you.  :-)